# Is there a hash algorithm that can efficiently calculate hashes of concatenated data?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Say we have a hash function `H`, and two byte strings `a` and `b` (might be long, e.g. seveal MiBs in size, so we want to avoid hashing them again). We already know the value of `H(a)` and `H(b)`, and want to calculate `H(a ++ b)` (The hash of two strings concatenated together).

We'd like to have a function `F` that can calculate `H(a ++ b)` from `H(a)`, `H(b)` and any other properties of `a` and `b` we can calculate beforehand (e.g. lengths), and takes less time than just hashing the whole string.

The hash function `H` doesn't need to be cryptographic, but should be good enough for HashMaps or similar usages.

Does such functions `H` and `F` exist? Or what should I search/research for if I'd like to know that?

---

#### Update 2022.01

After a bit more research, it seems that what I'm looking for is a hash function that **can** be attacked using a variant of [Length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) which doesn't even need to know the full value of the injected value.

Comment: Often `H(a ++ b) == xor(H(a), H(b))` is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Java's string hash is `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]` (modulo int size).

A property of this hash is that, `H(a++b) = (31^b.length())*H(a) + H(b)`.
You can compute `31^b.length()` using exponentiation by squaring in logarithmic time. If you wish to precompute, you can precompute `31^length` for each of your strings and store it with the precomputed hash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell more about what you expect from your hash function. Otherwise my answer is : use bit parity as a Hash because B(a++b)=(B(a)+B(b)) mod 2